# Javascript Round function

Tags: javascript

```
a                formula       b
31,283,700,000   round(a,-6)   31,284,000,000
60,204,605       round(a,-4)   60,200,000
```

I have an [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) formula to process the currency value,
but I have difficulties to achieve the same result by using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript),
any ideas to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158781/rounding-javascript-decimals) helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're alright with using a library, [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#round) has a method for this, `_.round(number, [precision=0]) - computes number rounded to precision`.

```js
console.log(_.round(31283700000, -6));
console.log(_.round(60204605, -4));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: wow .. having use this lodash for several times, but never know it is so great .. thanks @parker

Answer (score 3):

Rounding is easy to implement:

```js
function excelRound(n, e) {
  let f = Math.pow(10, e);
  return Math.round(n * f) / f;
}

console.log(31283700000, -6, excelRound(31283700000, -6));
console.log(60204605, -4, excelRound(60204605, -4));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a javascript rounding function which fixes javascript floating point rounding errors as well as takes care of what you were asking for. A more complete description can be found in [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158781/rounding-javascript-decimals).

Javascript floating point errors can occur as described by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken#588014):

> Binary floating point math is like this. In most programming
>   languages, it is based on the IEEE 754 standard. JavaScript uses
>   64-bit floating point representation, which is the same as Java's
>   double. The crux of the problem is that numbers are represented in
>   this format as a whole number times a power of two; rational numbers
>   (such as 0.1, which is 1/10) whose denominator is not a power of two
>   cannot be exactly represented.

```js
function round(number, precision) {
  number = +number;
  precision = precision ? +precision : 0;
  if (precision == 0) {
    return Math.round(number);
  }
  var sign = 1;
  if (number < 0) {
    sign = -1;
    number = Math.abs(number);
  }

  // Shift
  number = number.toString().split('e');
  number = Math.round(+(number[0] + 'e' + (number[1] ? (+number[1] + precision) : precision)));
  // Shift back
  number = number.toString().split('e');
  return +(number[0] + 'e' + (number[1] ? (+number[1] - precision) : -precision)) * sign;
}

console.log(round(31283700000, -6)) //31,284,000,000
console.log(round(60204605, -4)) //60,200,000
```